# Слияние веток, в одной из которых файлы были не переименованы, а удалены и созданы в другом каталоге

Tags: git, git-merge

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В последнем коммите ветки **hometype** есть изменения, которые должны быть в ветке **master**, но влить ее в мастер не получается, потому что в коммите **Rename** были изменены названия пакетов, что в общем означает новое местоположение файла/класса.

Получается, что в ветке **master** файлы, для которых есть изменения в **hometype**, находятся в других местах.

Как их теперь объединить, если это вообще возможно?

Comment: Прошу прощения за оффтопик, но какой программой вы пользуетесь для просмотра коммитов?

Comment: Я, честно говоря, подзабыл про гит почти все, что знал, но, возможно, вам поможет rebase с переносом коммитов. Попробуйте склонировать репозиторий в отдельную директорию и там поиграться с rebase.

Comment: для просмотра коммитов пользуюсь **GitKraken**

Comment: протестировал — внёс изменения в файл в другой ветке, в основной переименовал файл (`git mv старое-имя новое-имя; git commit`), после этого в основной ветке нормально прошла команда `git merge другая-ветка` (естественно, git предложил написать merge-сообщение). может быть, вы не переименовали файлы/каталоги (средствами git), а удалили/добавили (с точки зрения git-а)?

Comment: Как такового перемещения не было. Заказчику в библиотеке не понравилось название пакета (библиотека для Android), в итоге я с помощью рефакторинга, заменил все наименования пакетов на те которые захотел заказчики и закоммитил изменения. Судя по коммиту **Rename**, были удалены все файлы и добавлены новые с новыми путями. Хотя из **Android Studio** это выглядело как обычное переименовывание пакета.

Comment: Наконец-то нетривиальный вопрос про Git!

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а не хотите «заняться графоманством» и описать подробнее другой путь решения (я его вкратце озвучил в конце ответа)? а, может, и ещё какой-то совсем иной путь предложите.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо за предложение! Подумаю ещё, что тут можно сделать.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вообще на первый взгляд надо просто создать в мастере новый коммит, в котором аналогичным образом переименовать пакеты. А потом всё должно совпасть при слиянии.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а потом опять переименовать? кстати, совпадение пути и имёни в **разных** ветках для *git-а*, насколько я знаю, вовсе не является *однозначным* признаком того, что это один и тот же файл.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Зачем опять переименовать? В фичеветке же теперь те имена, которые хочет заказчик. Значит и в мастере они должны быть. Что касается совпадения пути и имени - думаю что сработает, не сталкивался с обратной ситуацией, хотя такие масштабные переименования делал нечасто.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, насколько я понял вопрос, переименование (и исправление) произошли как раз в ветке *master*, а в ветке *hometype* были изменения в «**старых**» файлах, и эти изменения не удаётся напрямую добавить в *master*.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42313/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-alexander-barakin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

судя по всему, *git* «не знает» о произведённых (в ветке `master`) переименованиях, и не может «связать» изменения, произведённые в другой (`hometype`) ветке (со «старыми» файлами), с файлами «новыми».

---

один из возможных (но не самый «изящный» из) путей «влить» изменения из другой ветки (`hometype`) в основную — получить *патч* из изменений, внесённых в ветке `hometype`, вручную исправить в нём имена файлов, и «наложить» *патч* в основной ветке командой `git apply файл.с.патчем` (см. [`man git-apply`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-apply.html)).

**совет**: тренироваться лучше на тестовой ветке, создав её командой `git checkout -b тестовая-ветка исходная-ветка`.

---

изменять надо будет такие примерно строки:

```
diff --git a/file1 b/file1
index 88621c5..af3bc11 100644
--- a/file1
+++ b/file1
```

здесь имя файла, которое надо будет вручную исправить — `file1`, оно встречается четыре раза, и все четыре его появления надо исправить. будьте внимательны: так как у вас были исправления, судя по всему, нескольких файлов, то блоков таких будет больше одного.

---

получить *патч* из изменений, внесённых *commit-ом*, зная его *хэш*, можно, например, так:

```
$ git diff хэш^ хэш
```

запись `хэш^` означает в данном случае «родительский» (*parent*) *commit* для данного *commit-а*.

см. [`man git-diff`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) на предмет подробностей об этой команде и [`man gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) о смысле `^` и подобных модификаторов.

---

в будущем я бы порекомендовал *переименования* файлов/каталогов делать *отдельным* коммитом (отдельным от изменения содержимого этих же файлов). тогда программа *git* без дополнительных указаний должна распознавать такие переименования.

другой путь решения озвученной в вопросе проблемы (он более «изящен», но требует довольно длинного описания) как раз и основывается на указании программе *git*, какую долю изменений в файле, «удалённом в одном месте и созданном в другом», следует считать переименованием. для команды `merge` это делается с помощью опции `rename-threshold` стратегии `recursive`. см. описание этой опции в `man git-merge` и опции `-M` в `man git-diff`.

Comment: Получилось **git apply --reject <file_name.patch>**, не без гемора конечно, но 90% патча применилось. Остальное ручками добавил.

Comment: @ViniPux, я ещё немного дополнил ответ.